# Youtube API Ref codes for PHP?

Tags: php, api, youtube

Looking for the object that allow to get the date of publication of a video.
I read Google Youtube API Doc but can't find any in that mess :(

I use V2 sentences :

```
$v->getVideoTitle();
```

Seems like to be easy using `$v->getVideoDate();` OR `$v->getVideoPublished();`
But not workin...

Some1 could help me ?

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

If you do a HTTP GET on the link below, with a given [video_id] it will return a XML response only including the partial request (in this case, "published").

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=[video_id]&max-results=1&fields=entry(published)&prettyprint=true
```

The result will be like this.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
    <entry>
        <published>2013-10-30T04:28:45.000Z</published>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Does this help you?

Comment: Well, it s not really helpin cuz i usin The Gdata V2 Api with Zend functions

 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');

 $yt   = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();

<?php echo $v->getVideoTitle(); ?>

I just need to find the request for getVideoRecorded()

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this?

<?php echo $v->getUpdated(); ?>